# SILEX PHP FORM - Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

Tags: php, datetime, doctrine-orm, doctrine, silex

I have a form in Silex with a field 'datetime'. When the form is submitted (save to database), it returns the error as below :

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in /home/(...)/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php on line 754

**EventType.php**

```
 <?php
  /**
   * Event type.
   *
   */

namespace Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

/**
 * Class EventType.
 *
 * @package Form
 */
class EventType extends AbstractType
{
/**
 * Form builder.
 *
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder Form builder
 * @param array $options Form options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add(
        'id',
        'hidden'
    );

    $builder->add(
        'name',
        'text',
        array(
            'label' => 'event.name',
            'required' => true,
        )
    );
    $builder->add(
        'startDate',
        'date',
        array(
            'label' => 'event.startDate',
            'required' => true,
        )
    );
    $builder->add(
        'endDate',
        'date',
        array(
            'label' => 'event.endDate',
        )
    );
    $builder->add(
        'startHour',
        'time',
        array(
            'label' => 'event.startHour',
        )
    );
    $builder->add(
        'endHour',
        'time',
        array(
            'label' => 'event.endHour',
        )
    );
    $builder->add(
        'periodicity',
        'number',
        array(
            'label' => 'event.periodicity',
        )
    );
}

/**
 * Getter for form name.
 *
 * @return string Form name
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'event_form';
}
}
```

**EventController**

```
<?php
 /**
  * Event controller.
  *
  */

namespace Controller;

use Silex\Application;
use Silex\ControllerProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

use Model\Events;
use Form\EventType;

/**
 * Class EventController.
 *
 * @package Controller
 *
 */
class EventController implements ControllerProviderInterface
{
/**
 * Routing settings.
 *
 * @param Silex\Application $app Silex application
 * @return Silex\ControllerCollection Result
 */
public function connect(Application $app)
{
    $eventController = $app['controllers_factory'];
    $eventController->get('', array($this, 'indexAction'))->bind('events');
    $eventController->get('/', array($this, 'indexAction'));
    $eventController->match('/add', array($this,'addAction'))->bind('events-add');
    $eventController->match('/add/', array($this,'addAction'));
    //$eventController->match('/edit/{id}', array($this, 'editAction'))->bind('event-edit');
    //$eventController->match('/delete/{id}', array($this, 'deleteAction'))->bind('event-delete');
    return $eventController;
}

/**
 * Index action.
 *
 * @param Silex\Application $app Silex application
 * @param Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request Request object
 * @return string Response
 */
public function indexAction(Application $app, Request $request)
{
    $view = array();
    //$events = new Events();
    //$view['events'] = $events->findAll();
    return $app['twig']->render('Event/index.html.twig', $view);
}

/**
 * Add action.
 *
 * @param Silex\Application $app Silex application
 * @param Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request Request object
 * @return string Response
 */
 public function addAction(Application $app, Request $request)
{
    $view = array();

    $addEventForm = $app['form.factory']
        ->createBuilder(new EventType(), array())->getForm();

    $addEventForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($addEventForm->isValid()) {
        $eventData = $addEventForm->getData();
        $eventModel = new Events($app);
        $eventModel->save($eventData);
        return $app->redirect(
            $app['url_generator']->generate('events'),
            301
        );
    }

    $view['form'] = $addEventForm->createView();
    return $app['twig']->render('Event/add.html.twig', $view);
}
}
```

**Events.php (model)**

```
<?php
/**
 * Events model.
 *
 */

namespace Model;

use Silex\Application;

/**
 * Class Events.
 *
 * @package Model
 * @use Silex\Application
 */
class Events
{
/**
 * Db access object.
 *
 * @var Silex\Provider\DoctrineSeviceProvider $db
 */
private $db = null;

/**
 * Events constructor.
 *
 * @param Application $app Silex application objecy
 */
public function __construct(Application $app)
{
    $this->db = $app['db'];
}

/**
 * Find all events.
 *
 * @return array Result
 */
public function findAll()
{
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM wydarzenie';
    $result = $this->db->fetchAll($query);
    return !$result ? array() : $result;
}

/**
 * Gets single event.
 *
 * @param integer $id Record Id
 * @return array Result
 */
public function find($id)
{
    if ($id != '' && ctype_digit((string)$id)) {
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM wydarzenie WHERE id= :id';
        $statement = $this->db->prepare($query);
        $statement->bindValue('id', $id, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $statement->execute();
        $result = $statement->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return !$result ? array() : current($result);
    } else {
        return array();
    }
}

/**
 * Save event.
 *
 * @param array $event Event data
 * @return mixed Result
 */
public function save($event)
{
    if(isset($event['id']) && $event['id'] != '' && ctype_digit((string)$event['id'])) {
        $id = $event['id'];
        unset($event['id']);
        return $this->db->update('wydarzenie', $event, array('id' => $id));
    } else {
        return $this->db->insert('wydarzenie',$event);
    }
}
}
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

Use doctrine orm

---

Or add data tranformers to form http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html

---

Or transform this fields manually on save

```
public function save($event)
{
$event['startDate'] = $event['startDate']->format($this->db->getDatabasePlatform()->getDateTimeFormatString());
...
```